# How to retrieve Google Drive folder's name using Javascript API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the version 3 of the API.
I have the ID of a folder. I want to get the name of the folder but I couldn't find out anywhere how to.

Comment: You should also tell use which version of the SDK you are using, as this will determine the answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's version 3.

Comment: you need to show us what you have tried and any errors you are getting.

Comment: @DaImTo I haven't tried anything yet because I have no clue where to start with this though.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that folders are a type of files in Google Drive. Using `files.get` with folder ID will retrieve the information of the folder.

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
   fileId:yourFolderId
});
request.execute(function(resp){
   var folderName = resp.name;
}};
```